# Partitioning Mysql table

Tags: mysql

What is the best method to partition a MySQL table(MyISAM)? table contains product details arranged by auto incrementing product id. It is expected to contain millions of records, so performance is essential.

Comment: The article [MySQL 5.1 partitions in practice](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/testing-partitions-large-db.html) gives some good tips and information on partitioning.